# Conditional probability when X is uniform on [-1, 1]

Tags: random-variables, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

*Let X be a real random variable that is uniformly distributed between -1 and +1. Intuitively, it is obvious that, for every y in R with 0<y<=1, we have*

*P(X=x|X^2=y) = 0 for x^2≠y*

*and*

*P(X=x|X^2=y) = 1/2 for x^2=y*

**Shouldn’t it be
P(X=x|X^2=y) = 1 for x^2=y ?**

Comment: First you need a definition of $P(A|B)$ when $B$ has probability zero.  Intuitively, if you know $X^2$, then there are two (equally likely) possibilities for $X$ itself.

Comment: Why are you asking?  What are you thinking that makes you suggest a different question?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly… you mean P(B) = 0 if x^2 ≠y

Comment: No, the way it is given is correct. Think about it. If $X^2 = y$, then x can either be $-\sqrt{y}$ or $\sqrt{y}$, and $X$ is uniform so they are equally likely. So the probability of either is $1/2$

Comment: Okay this makes kind of sense… sorry I’m new to this topic, still crawling! So you mean by the condition B all possible events left are sqrt(y) and -sqrt(y) ?

Comment: No worries, I think you're doing fine. Given that $X^2 = y$ then $X$ can take on two values as mentioned, $X = -\sqrt{y}$ and $\sqrt{y}$. So the conditional probability that $X$ takes on those two values is (.5 each) 1, and the conditional probability that $X$ takes on other than those two values is zero, if that's what you meant by 'possible events left' then yes

Comment: Thanks @Alborz!

Comment: Thanks also to @GEdgar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The basic idea of the conditional probability $P(.|B)$ is to set the
> probability measure to zero outside B and to rescale it inside B so
> that $P(B|B) = 1$

So we have  $P(B|B)=1$ and $P(B^c|B)=0$ ("$B^c$ "=not B).

$A: X$

$B: X^2=y$ , $B^c: X^2 \neq y$

$A|B=${$-\sqrt y ,\sqrt y$ }

$X=x$ is the event that the random variable X takes a value x

Since each value in $A|B$ has the same probability and $P(B|B)=1$ we have:

$P(X=x|X^2=y)=1/2$

Comment: I think you have the right idea but you want to be careful about how you define your events. Defining the event $A: X$ doesn't make too much sense. $X$ can take on different values, so $P(A) = 1$ for any outcome. What you want is $A: {X = x_k}$ for some $x_k$, say $x_k = y$, for example